# How do I minimise redundancy in a set of functional dependencies that can be trivial?

Tags: database-design, functional-dependencies

Let's say if I have a set that is {{AB->C}, {C->A}}. By transitivity, I get AB->A which is trivial. My candidate keys are possibly AB and BC. However, a tool I found tells me that the key is B.

How do I go about finding the key and its minimal cover?

Comment: *"However, a tool I found tells me that the key is B."* You need to find a different tool. The candidate keys are AB and BC. At least one algorithm is certainly in your textbook.